# Play Any Sound file (or at least the common audio files)

Tags: c#, audio, media-player, mediaelement, naudio

I am developing a music player in C#. For playing audio files, I have found that .NET provides many ways to play audio:

- Use a Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback via icrosoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll
- se a Windows Media Player control  via its COM Components

Right-click the Toolbox -> Choose item -> COM Components -> Locate and add the “Windows Media Player” ActiveX control

- Use [Naudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)
- Use the [MediaElement Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)

My question however is to choose the most appropriate method. Can someone suggest which method to choose considering that my application will only play major audio files (AAC, MP3, WMA, and WAV)? If possible, would you please tell what are the pros and cons of each method.
Thanks for your anticipated help!

Comment: You forgot the MediaElement class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX could be the best way but difficult to build.

MediaElement would be easier if you are developing WPF app as lower level implementation is taken care of by WPF.

WMP Activex control would need a good amount of tweaking if you need custom UI  and the documentation online in MSDN leaves a lot to be desired.

I myself have developed players using WPF and WMP activeX control and the one with WPF media element has been pretty stable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm really hesitating now as I am afraid I might end up on a tough road ahead. At least your comment will help me minimize the pain